# using a switch statement - but case where counter equals one never gets used

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, counter

array switch 
    Sample Use the array switch button to toggle through a number of combinations

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   var clcks = 0; 
    $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
    var curFnt = ['Trebuchet MS', 'Verdana', 'Tahoma', 'Palatino',  'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Arial', 'Courier New'];
   var txtClr =['Black', 'Red','Green','Blue','Brown','Aqua','Gold','white','black'];
    var curBkC = ['white', 'aqua','brown','yellow','lightGreen','orange','blue','lightBlue','LightSeaGreen']    
   var msg = '';                   // Message

      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
     // Add 1 to the current round
      clcks = (clcks + 1); 
      if(clcks>=8)clcks=1;

                            switch (true) {
        case clcks == 1:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break;                  
        case clcks == 2:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break;
        case clcks == 3:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break;
        case clcks == 4:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
          case clcks == 5:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "slow");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
        case clcks == 6:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
        case clcks == 7:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
        case clcks == 8:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);

            break; 
                            }


  } );

      });
```

Here is a sample of my file online -  the first font selected by the 'array switch' button should be 'Trebuchet MS' but instead it skips to Verdana       http://etherealdoorways.com/switchColorFont.html

Comment: that's not how switch case works

Comment: and you dont really need it either. there's a lot of repetitive code there, you need to practice DRY(dont repeat yourself) code.

Answer (score 0):

You've initialized the clcks variable to 0, but it is incremented by 1 upon the first click.

The clcks should begin at 0 so that it can be used to access the first element in the arrays.

Initialize the clcks to 7 instead of 0 on document ready. 
Also, if clcks is equal or larger than 8, it should be reset to 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   // Initialize to 7, so that the first click will return to 0
   var clcks = 7; 
    $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
    var curFnt = ['Trebuchet MS', 'Verdana', 'Tahoma', 'Palatino',  'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Arial', 'Courier New'];
   var txtClr =['Black', 'Red','Green','Blue','Brown','Aqua','Gold','white','black'];
    var curBkC = ['white', 'aqua','brown','yellow','lightGreen','orange','blue','lightBlue','LightSeaGreen']    
   var msg = '';                   // Message

      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
     // Add 1 to the current round
      clcks = (clcks + 1); 

      // This should be reset to 0, not 1
      // Also, change index numbers in switch-case so that clcks is also 0-based
      if(clcks>=8)clcks=0;

                            switch (true) {
        case clcks == 0:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break;                  
        case clcks == 1:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break;
        case clcks == 2:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break;
        case clcks == 3:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
          case clcks == 4:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "slow");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
        case clcks == 5:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
        case clcks == 6:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);
            break; 
        case clcks == 7:
            $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '34px'}, "fast");
            $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
            $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);

            break; 
                            }


  } );

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement is formatted incorrectly. You need to put your expression on the switch and the values on the case like so:

```
switch(clcks) {
  case 1:
     : 
    break;
  case 2:
     :
    break;
  :
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch case needs an expression to compare against the cases. But you dont really need it either.

It goes straight to Verdana cos you're adding 1 to clcks before executing the code (in JS, array index starts from 0).

Here's what I think you need (untested code):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   // Declare all variables outside of the on click
   var clcks = 0; 
   var curFnt = ['Trebuchet MS', 'Verdana', 'Tahoma', 'Palatino',  'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Arial', 'Courier New'];
   var txtClr =['Black', 'Red','Green','Blue','Brown','Aqua','Gold','white','black'];
   var curBkC = ['white', 'aqua','brown','yellow','lightGreen','orange','blue','lightBlue','LightSeaGreen']    
   var msg = '';
   $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){

      if( clcks >= 8 ) clcks = 1;

        $(".sample2").css({
          'background-color'     : curBkC[clcks],
          'font-family'          : curFnt[clcks],
          'color'                : txtClr[clcks]
        });
        $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
        $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '38px'}, "fast");
        $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast"); // Not sure why you have 2 of these
        $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);  

        clcks = (clcks + 1); // Put after executing your on click code

     });
});
```

Also, try to make your variable names readable so if you're collaborating with others they can understand what each one represents straight away.

Comment: You forgot the altering font size (38, 34)

Comment: This works.  The second time through the button sequence the counter reset needed to be changed to if (clcks >= 8) clcks = 0;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a switch statement at all (apart from that it is is written the wrong way)

The first time the function is called, `clcks` in incremented to 1, which means that the array elements at index 1 are read instead of the elements at index 0.

Here's a better, working solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var curFnt = ['Trebuchet MS', 'Verdana', 'Tahoma', 'Palatino',  'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Arial', 'Courier New'];
    var fontSizes = ["38px", "34px", "38px", "34px", "38px", "34px", "38px", "34px"];
    var txtClr = ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Aqua', 'Gold', 'white', 'black'];
    var curBkC = ['white', 'aqua', 'brown', 'yellow', 'lightGreen', 'orange', 'blue', 'lightBlue', 'LightSeaGreen'];

    var clcks = 0;

    $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
        var msg = '';

        // clcks is incremented at the end of the function
        // -> clcks is 0 at the first time

        $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
        $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
        $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
        $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
        $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: fontSizes[clcks]}, "fast");
        $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
        $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);

        clcks = clcks + 1;
        if (clcks >= 8) clcks = 1;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I will use:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var curFnt = ['Trebuchet MS', 'Verdana', 'Tahoma', 'Palatino',  'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Arial', 'Courier New'];
    var fontSizes = ["38px", "34px", "38px", "34px", "38px", "34px", "38px", "34px"];
    var txtClr = ['Black', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Aqua', 'Gold', 'white', 'black'];
    var curBkC = ['white', 'aqua', 'brown', 'yellow', 'lightGreen', 'orange', 'blue', 'lightBlue', 'LightSeaGreen'];

    var clcks = 0;

    $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
        var msg = '';

        // clcks is incremented at the end of the function
        // -> clcks is 0 at the first time

        $(".sample2").css('background-color', curBkC[clcks]);
        $(".sample2").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
        $("#currFont").css("font-family", curFnt[clcks]);
        $(".sample2").css("color", txtClr[clcks]);
        $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: fontSizes[clcks]}, "fast");
        $(".sample2").animate({fontSize: '36px'}, "fast");
        $("#currFont").html(curFnt[clcks]);

        clcks = clcks + 1;
        if (clcks >= 8) clcks = 0;
            });
        });
```